# Google Bot (SEO) and language using cookies but have the exact same url

Tags: seo, googlebot

is there any way that I can inform the google bot that to get additional languages it needs to have a cookie set?

for example, at https://www.famistar.com the user can click at the bottom of the page to change language. What really happens under the hood is that the button via js will set a cookie and will reload the page.

Is there any way (withought modifying the urls or adding a url parameter for language) that we can notify google bot to crawl all provided languages?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: I am aware of this but this doesn't say anything about telling the bot to use cookie to access the different languages. As my question states I would rather do this withought adding some url parameter - only with the cookie

Comment: Google says,
Language-dependent crawling

If your site alters its content based on any Accept-Language field set by browsers’ HTTP headers, Googlebot uses a variety of signals to try to crawl your content using different Accept-Language HTTP headers. This means Google is more likely to discover, index, and rank your content in the different languages your site supports.

Any idea how to supply a list of locales it can try?

Answer (score 1):

Google can't read cookies and sessions To prove this, use "Developer Tools" on any browser and disable the cookies.

The only way that Google can index and crawl your languages is to add them as a level in the URL `example.com/en` or add them as sub-domain `en.example.com` or parameter.

Also don't forget to add "hreflang" in the `<head>` to make sure Google will understand your structure.

Comment: I don't see how disabling cookies in developer tools "proves" anything.  That setting may simulate how Googlebot acts to some degree, but "proof?"

Answer (score 0):

Google only ever indexes one page worth of content for a specific URL.  Even if you could get Googlebot to change the language, every time it recrawled the URL with different cookies, it would overwrite its indexing data for other languages.

The only way to have Google index content in multiple languages is to have different URLs for each language.  See [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization)

In any case, Googlebot doesn't use cookies that persist between pages.  Googlebot fetches each page with an empty cookie jar.  It does so because users that click through to your site from Google are not going to start with any cookies set for your site.